# Cloudability AWS Amazon API Gateway Widget Set Up

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to set up a widget in Cloudability that will track the costs of a specific Amazon API Gateway. In the filter steps I set `Service Equals Amazon API Gateway` but I am unsure which further filters I need. The gateway resources are [image: Resource]

**What are the correct filter steps I need here?**

Comment: Can you point to any documentation you are following? I work on API Gateway but have no familiarity with Cloudability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response from Cloudability support: "after digging, I do not believe that there is a way to surface the key/value stage variables for the API Gateways at this time"